# VS2017 and AnkhSVN

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2017, ankhsvn

My solution is detected properly by AnkhSVN running in VS2015 to be bound to SVN. For some reason, if I open this same solution in Visual Studio 2017, AnkhSVN doesn't see it bound to SVN. I try to bind it, for some reason VS2017 binds it to GIT. Not sure why that is. What is the proper way to fix this issue? or how do I re-bind it again to SVN so that AnkhSVN sees it as bound?

P.S. This doesn't happen in all my solutions, just a few. Not sure what is so special about those solutions. Did diffs but I don't see anything special about those solutions. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried switching the source-control settings in **VS | Tools | Options | Source Control**? Don't forget to check that AnkhSVN is actually installed in your VS2017 instance. In case nothing helps, take a look at [VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/). VisualSVN is free in case your computer is not in AD domain and we've sim-shipped the latest 6.0 version with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @bahrep - checked it. It says: "Current source control plug-in: "AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio". The thing is that it works for other solutions, just a few seem to be exhibiting this strange behavior.

Comment: @bahrep, I realized that this setting is on a per-solution basis and not a general VS setting. If you want to get credit for your answer please post as an answer and I will remove the answer I put for myself (in case I ever hit this issue again)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems the way to fix this is to go to 
"Tools - Options - Source Control", and select AnkhSVN as the active SCC Provider.

This seems to be on a per solution basis and it makes some change in the solution file because it works from then on.